# Hackerrank stdin only gives me the first line from multiple lines

Tags: swift

I am trying to solve this challenge on HackerRank:
https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/30-operators?h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen

the way I tried to read the stdin is this:

`let input = readline()!`

However, the input consists of three lines, e.g.

```
12.00
20
8
```

How do I get all three lines, ideally in some separated way so that I can cast them to their respective types?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need the 3 lines, call it 3 times :)

The documentation is explicit

> Returns Characters read from standard input through **the end of the
>   current line** or until EOF is reached, or nil if EOF has already been
>   reached.

But it seems they forgot to indicate that reading a line will change the *current line*

Comment: I'd also love to know how to do that. Reason being, I just tried out a HackerRank challenge as well, and if a question gives you x lines of input, putting x lines of let someVariable = readLine() simply doesn't cut it, because there are lot's of test cases that shoot way more input to the code we write, so hard coded readLine() for each line of input won't fly.

Comment: @PeterParker That's a new question and should be asked as such .
You want to search for loop control such as for or while.

Answer (score 0):

Generally what I would do is use input() to assign the stdin values to a variable and then pass the variables for functions.

example:

```
a = input() #gives the first line
b = input() #gives the second line
c = input() #gives the third line
```

if you would like to read all the lines then use a for loop:
example:

```
import sys
for line in sys.stdin:
  print(line)
```